# Is there any source for throwing bread during tashlich?

Tags: minhag, sources-mekorot, rosh-hashanah-new-year, bread, tashlich

Is there a reliable Jewish source that encourages throwing bread when performing tashlich?

Comment: Some are against it because when the body of water is in a public place carrying the bread to the water would be problematic on yomtov. Since it is for no purpose

Comment: Maybe the Tammei Minhagim discusses this

Comment: To my knowledge, every source that discusses the practice of throwing bread to the fish by Tashlich is opposed to it.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13861

Comment: @sam, it doesn't AFAICT.